# Having trouble renaming files in subdirectories (With conditions) [shell scripting]

Tags: shell, file-rename

## I am not succeeding at writing a proper code!

My directory is like this

```
/Users/dave/yellow/shade001/light
/Users/dave/yellow/shade001/dark1
/Users/dave/yellow/shade001/dark2
...
/Users/dave/yellow/shade999/light
/Users/dave/yellow/shade999/dark1
/Users/dave/yellow/shade999/dark2
```

There are about 999 shade folders inside yellow directory, each contains
    2 or 3 files (`light` always present, `dark1` always present, and `dark2` sometime present). I would like to rename `light`, `dark1` and delete `dark2` such that:

```
light.txt renamed to lgt.txt

dark1.txt renamed to dk1.txt

dark2 (whenever found) should be deleted
```

Here is what i did:

`for /r %x in (light.txt) do ren "%x" lgt.txt
   for /r %x in (dark1.txt) do ren "%x" dk1.txt
   find . -type f -name 'dark2' -delete
   done`

Comment: And... what is the problem? Where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash or similar shell:

```
find shade* -name light.txt | while read NAME; do mv $NAME `dirname $NAME`/lgt.txt; done
```

Analogically with `dark1` and `dark2` (rm instead of mv in the latter case).

Comment: You mean:
    find shade* -name light.txt | while read NAME; do mv $NAME `dirname     $NAME`/lgt.txt; done
    find shade* -name dark1.txt | while read NAME; do mv $NAME `dirname $NAME`/dk1.txt; done
    find shade* -name dark2.txt | while read NAME; do rm $NAME `dirname $NAME`; done

Comment: No, the last one should be  `find shade* -name dark2.txt | while read NAME; do rm $NAME; done`

Comment: Or simpler: `find shade* -name dark2.txt -exec rm {} \;`. By the way, be careful with such commands because a small mistake may delete other files...

Comment: Thank you. I always try delete commands on dummy files first!

Comment: @helpme If it works for you, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer ;)